# Cassandra query failure (Tombstones)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-node-driver

So this is driving me crazy. i tried querying one of my table in Cassandra and it showed query failure. i tried digging dip in to the reason behind it and found that it was because of tombstone. i changed GC_GRACE_SECONDS to Zero and triggered Compaction using nodetool, And when i queried again it worked fine. however on a subsequent calls query failed again with a same reason. i am using cassandra-nodejs driver.
This is my data model.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    email text,
    mobile text,
    date timeuuid,
    value float,
    PRIMARY KEY (firstname, lastname, email, mobile)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (lastname ASC, email ASC, mobile ASC);
```

this is the query i want to perform on that data model.

```
SELECT firstname, email, toDate(date) as date, mobile, value FROM my_table  WHERE date >= minTimeuuid('2017-03-25 00:00:00+0000') AND date <= minTimeuuid('2017-03-28 23:59:59+0000') ALLOW FILTERING;
```

the result will have approx 40k rows.
[this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets) shows that if we delete something it will be marked as tombstone and will get deleted After GC_GRACE_SECONDS setted for given table. If i understand it correctly then.

1. how come there be tombstone problem when i never delete any row of table?
2. Is that true a row will be marked as Tombstone if and only if we delete a row?
3. clearing tombstones and then querying the same works sometimes and sometimes it does not, why is so?.
4. is it a good idea to increase **tombstone_failure_threshold** value? (single node cluster application)

I am using cassandra 3.5, with cqlsh version 5.0.1. And the query works fine with terminal, but gives error when we execute using external client (express app using nodejs driver for cassandra). i have a single node cluster app.

#### EDIT 1

This is the log of my Inserted null value in field (i inserted only name and timestamp);

```
  activity                                                                                        | timestamp                  | source        | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------
                                                                              Execute CQL3 query | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342000 | 172.31.34.179 |              0
                   Parsing select * FROM testtomb WHERE name = 'Dhaval45'; [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342000 | 172.31.34.179 |             64
                                                       Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342000 | 172.31.34.179 |            101
                              Executing single-partition query on testtomb [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342000 | 172.31.34.179 |            210
                                              Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342000 | 172.31.34.179 |            223
 Skipped 0/0 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342000 | 172.31.34.179 |            243
                                 Merged data from memtables and 0 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342000 | 172.31.34.179 |            288
                                         Read 2 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342001 | 172.31.34.179 |            310
                                 Merged data from memtables and 0 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342001 | 172.31.34.179 |            323
                                                                                Request complete | 2017-03-29 10:28:27.342385 | 172.31.34.179 |            385
```

And this is the log when i query on filed which i have executed a delete query. Initially  user **Dhaval15** has firstname 'aaaa' and then i the cell aaa. then again executing select query on same user gave me this log.

```
       activity                                                                                        | timestamp                  | source        | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------
                                                                              Execute CQL3 query | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581000 | 172.31.34.179 |              0
                   Parsing select * FROM testtomb WHERE name = 'Dhaval15'; [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581000 | 172.31.34.179 |             65
                                                       Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581000 | 172.31.34.179 |            113
                              Executing single-partition query on testtomb [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581000 | 172.31.34.179 |            223
                                              Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581000 | 172.31.34.179 |            235
 Skipped 0/0 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581000 | 172.31.34.179 |            256
                                 Merged data from memtables and 0 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581001 | 172.31.34.179 |            305
                                         Read 1 live and 1 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581001 | 172.31.34.179 |            338
                                 Merged data from memtables and 0 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581001 | 172.31.34.179 |            351
                                                                                Request complete | 2017-03-29 10:35:18.581430 | 172.31.34.179 |            430
```

Comment: Would you please provide the failure message? The exception log that is generating.

Comment: I keep on getting **Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures**  . {traceQuery : true } option is not working somehow and on terminal the query runs successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cassandra tombstone created even if you don't execute delete query, when you insert null value.

Tombstone consume space. When you execute select query cassandra needs to filter out data by tombstone. If huge tombstone generated your select query performance will degrade.

Your query failing because of huge tombstone and `ALLOW FILTERING`. Don't use `ALLOW FILTERING` on production. it's very costy. When you execute query without specifying partition key, Cassandra needs to scan all the row of all the nodes.

Change your data model to like the below one :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    year int,
    month int,
    date timeuuid,
    email text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    mobile text,
    value float,
    PRIMARY KEY ((year, month), date)
);
```

Here you can specify year and month extract from the date.
Now you can query with specifying partition key :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE year = 2017 AND month = 03 AND date >= minTimeuuid('2017-03-25 00:00:00+0000') AND date <= minTimeuuid('2017-03-28 23:59:59+0000') ;
```

This will return result very efficiently and will not fail.

If you need to query with firstname and lastname create an index on them

```
CREATE INDEX index_firstname ON my_table (firstname) ;
CREATE INDEX index_lastname ON my_table (lastname) ;
```

Then you can query with firstname or last name

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE firstname = 'ashraful' ;
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE lastname  = 'islam' ;
```

Here i have not create index on email and phone because of high cardinality problem. Instead create materialized view or another table to query with phone or email

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mview_mobile AS
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table
    WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL AND year IS NOT NULL AND month IS NOT NULL AND date IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (mobile, year, month, date);


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mview_email AS
        SELECT *
        FROM my_table
        WHERE email IS NOT NULL AND year IS NOT NULL AND month IS NOT NULL AND date IS NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY (email, year, month, date);
```

Now you can query with phone or email

```
SELECT * FROM mview_mobile WHERE mobile = '018..';
SELECT * FROM mview_email WHERE email = 'ashraful@...';
```

More about cassandra tombstone : http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

Comment: i will try but still am confused about sometimes clearing tombstones work and sometimes they dont? why is so?

Comment: Tombstone consume space. When you execute select query cassandra needs to filter out data by tombstone. If huge tombstone generated your select query performance will degrade.

Comment: if i dont want to change my table structure is there any other way?

Comment: Then check your all insert and update statement, ensure that no null value inserted

Comment: Thanks for the time :)

Comment: How about if i model my table like this PRIMARY KEY **((firstname, lastname, email, mobile,date))** i mean i use multiple primary keys and not any clustering key? will it cause problems?

Comment: Then you can't use any query without specifying firstname, lastname, email, mobile and date. Then you have to use ALLOW FILTERING which is very costly and not recomanded

Comment: i tried to dig in, but i found that tombstone are getting created only on deleting cell/row. So how do they are affecting in my case.

Comment: Mainly two things affecting you, First ALLOW FILTERING and second tombstone

Comment: yes thats true, but i dont find tombstone gets created on insert.. is it true?

Comment: If you insert only name and timestamp, tombstone will not created, but if you insert explicitly value null then tombstone will created like `insert into (pk1,pk2, ck1,ck2, d1,d2) values(1,10,100,1000, null,null);`

Comment: whats the point of creating index? lets say i want to get range of values and i have indexed the value column. i will eventually have to use allow filtering right? in that case (without Allow Filtering) i will have to use materialized view to support that kind of query right?

Answer (score 1):

> > 1. how come there be tombstone problem when i never delete any row of table?

@Ashraful Islam's answer is correct.

In addition,
If you explicitly insert data with NULL values, it will internally create tombstones.

Ex: insert into my_table (firstname,lastname,email,mobile, .....) values ('abd', 'gef', 'xxx@abc.com', '+67899...', null, null, .....);

There will be null values for other columns (internally generating tombstones as Cassandra has to indicate with something that those columns do not exists or have values).

As you have mentioned too many columns as primary keys it will create too large wide rows (which is also  discouraged) with too many null values thus end up with lots of tombstones. It may have crossed the threshold limit in you case.

As @Ashraful stated this data model is not okay. As you need to query by time
you should design your model such that you can do some range queries on time. Query without mentioning partition key thus using ALLOW FILTERING in a large data set is an anti-pattern in Cassandra.

> > 2. Is that true a row will be marked as Tombstone if and only if we delete a row?

You can delete a complete or a specific column. If a row is deleted, the entire row is marked as tombstone. If a specific column is deleted (or insert/UPDATE NULL value) tombstones will be created on that specific column (which is also discouraged) I guess that happens in your case.

> > 3. clearing tombstones and then querying the same works sometimes and sometimes it does not, why is so?.

I think you may now determine why this happens :).

> > 4. is it a good idea to increase tombstone_failure_threshold value? (single node cluster application)

Increasing tombstone_failure_threshold will just lessen the amount of error but does not solve the actual problem. It will not increase performance and cross the threshold as data set increases.

And importantly, in single node cluster application you can set GC_GRACE_SECONDS to 0. Tombstones will be deleted instantly after compaction occurs. GC_GRACE_SECONDS is vital while using multi-node cluster which is the actual purpose of using NoSQL I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the time :) and yeah it may happen that there are too many null columns in each row

Comment: I think before you model your data in Cassandra, you should follow some basic rules. There are so many articles on that. 

You have put all the columns as partition key which means you have restricted the query (you have to mention all column in where clause). Can you provide all the values? 

Again it does not solve the allow filtering problem. You still cannot do range query by time. To support your query, you still have to read data without mentioning partition key thus end up using ALLOW FILTERING.

Comment: FYI, C* uses partition key to locate the node in which the requested row resides. Now you have to mention all the values to inform C* which node she has to request to get data. Again you have already changed your data structure. then why not change the model as per your query :)

Comment: yeah i dont mind changing it. but just a bit curious to know about the things.

Comment: Check if you explicitly insert null values. Check the example I have provided in my answer.

Comment: You cannot provide null values in primary key. Check if 'date' column is inserted null. 

Ex: insert into my_table (firstname,lastname,email,mobile, date) values ('abd', 'gef', 'xxx@abc.com', '+67899...', null);